# .Net Core Blazor A type error occurred and I tried to convert it but it didn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(TResult)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Return **cmsProduct. Count = = 0** error: when The type arguments for The method 'System. The Threading. Tasks. Task. FromResult (TResult)' always be inferred from The usage

Code:

```
    @foreach (var item in cmsProduct)
    {
     <li>
        <h4>@item.CategoryName</h4>
        <img src="@url" alt="@item.Title"><span>ProductName</span>
     </li>
    }

@code {
 private IList<dynamic> cmsProduct = new List<dynamic>();

 protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
 {
    cmsProduct = await cmsProductService.GetShowProductList(Id);
 }
}



public Task<List<dynamic>> GetShowProductList(string id)
{
    using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
    { 
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<CmsContext>();
        DapperContext dapperContext = new DapperContext(context);

        string sql = "SELECT p.Id,p.Title,p.ImgUrl,p.Summary,nm.Url,pc.CategoryName FROM CmsProduct p LEFT JOIN CmsNavMenu nm ON (p.NavMenuId = nm.Id) LEFT JOIN CmsProductCategory pc ON (pc.NavMenuId=nm.Id) where p.Deleted='" + false + "' and p.NavMenuId='" + id + "'";

        IEnumerable<dynamic> dynamicResults = dapperContext.Query<dynamic>(sql);

        var result = dynamicResults.ToList();

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You code works fine for me. Is there a minimal demo that reproduce the same issue?

Comment: How to solve this problem here:The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(TResult)' cannot be inferred from the usage

Comment: 1. Is that error a compile-time error or a runtime error? 2. When you say "Returns a set that failed when set Count is 0": Did you mean if `dynamicResults==new List<dynamic>{}`, it throws such an exception?   3 Is there a minimal demo that reproduces?

Comment: runtime error   cmsProduct = await cmsProductService.GetShowProductList(Id);(cmsProduct .Count==0) error.Is the error that did not query to data, how to deal with excuse me

Comment: This error occurred when the returned set cmsproduct.count ==0. error:The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(TResult)' cannot be inferred from the usage

Comment: Still cannot reproduce. Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: The above questions are

Comment: Ctrl+F :cmsProduct